# Zend Framework 2 navigation. Adding ul class to sub menu recursively

Tags: php, html, navigation, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I am using view helper Navigation and attempt to add class to sub menu.
Method setUlClass() adds class only for first level of the menu.

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
    <ul class="nav main-menu">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/administrator">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="hidden-xs"> Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/administrator/content/news">
                <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
                <span class="hidden-xs"> News</span>
            </a>
            <ul>   <!-- <-- here want to add class -->
                <li>
                    <a href="/administrator/content/add-news">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs"> Add News</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

module.config.php file bellow:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => '<i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> News</span>',
                'route' => 'admin/default',
                'controller' => 'content',
                'action' => 'news',
                'resource'  => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                'pages' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> Add News</span>',
                        'route' => 'admin/default',
                        'controller' => 'content',
                        'action' => 'add-news',
                        'resource'  => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

In view call render method:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setUlClass('nav main-menu')->escapeLabels(false); ?>
```

How to do that?

Comment: How about using a custom partial and doing that there?

Comment: yes, already did that

Answer (score 0):

I think that in ZF2 is the same Class code as in ZF1.
And no solution by setting a config option, you see in \Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu::renderNormalMenu() this code block:

```
if ($depth > $prevDepth) {
    // start new ul tag
    if ($ulClass && $depth ==  0) {
        $ulClass = ' class="' . $escaper($ulClass) . '"';
    } else {
        $ulClass = '';
    }
        $html .= $myIndent . '<ul' . $ulClass . '>' . PHP_EOL;  
 }
```

btw css could be applied for sub ul tags :

```
ul.nav.main-menu ul {
  ...
}
```